# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError No provider for AlertPanelComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-injector

Error message:

> ERROR NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AlertPanelComponent -> AlertPanelComponent
> -> AlertPanelComponent]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for AlertPanelComponent!
> Angular

I do not understand this, I am just trying to import my `AlertPanelComponent` from the alert-panel.component.

This error seems to be very broad when searching on stackOverflow. I have put this in my app.module.

app.component.ts

```
import {AlertClass} from './models/alert-class.model';
...
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
    ...
    constructor( private restService:RestService,
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        private router:Router, 
        private alertPanelComponent:AlertPanelComponent ){
    }
    ...
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AlertPanelComponent } from './alert-panel/alert-panel.component';
...
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AlertPanelComponent,
        ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, 
    Routes,
    PreloadAllModules} from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {AlertPanelComponent} from './alert-panel/alert-panel.component';
import {WebCamComponent} from './web-cam/web-cam.component';
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '',component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'alert-panel',component: AlertPanelComponent},
    {path: 'webcam', component: WebCamComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: The `app.component.ts` code is actually `app.module`. Have you injected `AlertPanelComponent` in a `constructor` ?

Comment: yes i did. it is in the app.module.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, did you generate the component through the CLI?
because that usually do some import work, check that.

Second, can you show me your app-routing.module.ts, this is a prime candidate for nullInjectorError.

Adding AlertPanelComponent to your app-component constructor imposes that you add it as a provider in your app-module.

Components do not behave that way, either change it to a provider, or in your case, judging by your code, you have no use of actually AlertPanelComponent in your app-component

Comment: It has been awhile but i did generate the alert-panel component.

Also I have updated to include the app-routing.module.ts.

Comment: You mean you updated the app-routing.module.ts to include alert-panel component right?

Comment: I mean I have updated in the question to include app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Why did you add AlertPanelComponent in the app-component constructor?

Comment: I was trying to access alerts from app.component

Comment: Thanks I learnt something today. I will take a break now, and try later. I will probably use a service or dump things in sessionStorage.

Comment: To think of it, to share variables across components, it is a good idea to use Angular Services instead of importing another component. WebStorage API is useful but it doesn't seem to be as useful as Angular Services.

Comment: Depending on the case, for some data I use angular services, for others I just use localStorage, that being said, these are not the only two options